# How does xbacklight work?

Tags: intel-graphics, backlight

I just noticed that if I uninstall `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, then `xbacklight` will stop working and give this error: `No outputs have backlight property`, although it worked flawlessly before that. This makes me curious about how xbacklight actually does its job, especially why it does not require `sudo`, while if I want to manually adjust `/sys/class/backlight/apci_video0/brightness` then I will need to either use sudo or modify the permissions. I did try to look at the source code of xbacklight, but I'm not at all familiar with C or C++ so I cannot understand anything.